# pass mobx observable data to props

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Using mobx in react-typescript project. This class set observable array with fetch api:

```
class MenuRepo {
  @observable menuItems?: IMenuModel[];//=[{Id:1,itemName:"asd",childItems:[]}];
  @action getItems(): void {
    fetch(`...`)
      .then((response: { value: IMenuModel[] }): void => {
        this.menuItems = [
          { Id: 1, itemName: 'test-item1', childItems: [] }
        ];
      });
  }
```

and I want to track this observable data in this component class:

```
@observer
class Menu extends React.Component<{params?:IMenuModel[]}, {}> {
  render() {
    debugger
    var menuJSX : JSX.Element[] = this.props.params ? this.props.params.map((item:IMenuModel, i:number)=>{
      return (<li key={item.Id}>{item.itemName}</li>)
    }):[];
    return (...)
```

but params is "undefined". I watched some tutorials about mobx&react but couldnt solve it.

and here App.tsx file:

```
import menuCodes from './components/Codes';
class App extends React.Component<null, null> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Menu params = {asd.menuItems}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `asd` instanceof `MenuRepo`? Note that in the first render menuItems will be undefined, as it only get's it's first value after the fetch has resolved, which should produce the second rendering.

Note that `App` should be `observer` as that is the one dereferencing the `menuItems` observable. (For more info: https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html)

Comment: Actually u already solved my issue with the link of an article you shared in twitter. Thank you :)